# Decoding of unknown formatting

Tags: c#, web-scraping

I am getting data from website through scraper written in C#. I am getting data in following unknown format. Need to know, if any body can help me to read and parse this format:

```
{"atgResponse": "{\"iTotalDisplayRecords\":5,\"cache\":[],\"iTotalRecords\":5,\"aaData\":[[\"{\\\"lineCode\\\":\\\"CHL\\\",\\\"applicationQuestions\\\":\\\"{}\\\",\\\"techNoteCode\\\":0,\\\"quickNoteCode\\\":0,\\\"type\\\":\\\"nonNegativeOne\\\",\\\"productId\\\":\\\"prod11240295\\\",\\\"pricing\\\":{\\\"formatted\\\":{\\\"core\\\":\\\"$0.00\\\",\\\"list\\\":\\\"$21.00\\\",\\\"cost\\\":\\\"$10.50\\\"},\\\"showCoreCost\\\":false,\\\"unformatted\\\":{\\\"core\\\":0,\\\"list\\\":21,\\\"cost\\\":10.5},\\\"dealsForItem\\\":\\\"SAVE ON FILTERS~Save on Autolite Oil and STP Oil, STP Air and STP Cabin Air Filters, 20% off, only have to buy 1~Offer valid through 01/16/2016~70035~false~~https://contentinfo.autozonepro.com/znetcs/product-info/en/US/chl/SA10539/image/~true~false~null~|\\\",\\\"hasInstoreDeal\\\":true,\\\"hasOnlineDeal\\\":false},\\\"id\\\":\\\"sku11314924\\\",\\\"fit\\\":true,\\\"grayedOut\\\":false,\\\"skuType\\\":\\\"partSku\\\",\\\"name\\\":\\\"Air Filter\\\",\\\"oemBrand\\\":\\\"Hyundai\\\",\\\"skuId\\\":\\\"sku11314924\\\",\\\"brand\\\":\\\"STP\\\",\\\"displayName\\\":\\\"STP / Air
```

Comment: Looks like JSON wrapping a JSON value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's JSON wrapped in JSON.

**atgResponse** is a JSON property that has a string value. The string value contains another JSON object (that has been escaped).

The ending looks like it has been truncated though. There should be more to come but it is missing.

This appears to be coming from Oracle ATG: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24152_01/Platform.10-1/ATGWSFrameGuide/html/s1313choosingoutputmarkup01.html

Comment: YES, you are right. There is more data coming. But I posted just couple of lines. Can you please give me a tip, how to decode this?

Comment: Yes, use JSON.NET (http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)